# Is there a way to make the DNN Host account User Switcher part of the Admin functionality, not just Host?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a requirement to allow portal Admins the ability to impersonate a site user, not the Host account(s) and limit the users the Admin can impersonate to only users of the portal.  Can this be done in DotNetNuke or would this require all custom coding/module development?

Comment: I'm a little confused. What function in the Host "User Switcher" do you need that isn't currently available to the portal Admin? The Admins can already impersonate normal users of their portal.

Comment: Are you referring to this module http://identityswitcher.codeplex.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Become User module at http://[www.dnnspot.com](http://www.dnnspot.com) I think it does exactly what you want, it's like 10 bucks.

Comment: I ended up reverse engineering a module using Reflector based upon the Host-level User Switcher module.  We needed too many customizations to use a third-party module.  Works fine.